# ngAria : setting aria-invalid to false

Tags: angularjs, wai-aria

Im using ngaria in my angularjs project and I have 3 radio buttons where each has the same ngModel and the values are different.

```
                <label for="radio">
                    <input type="radio" value="a" name="someName" id="radio"                              ng-model="someModel"
                           aria-checked="false">radio one
                </label>
                <label for="radio2" >
                    <input type="radio" value="b" name="someName"
                           id="radio2" aria-checked="false"                             
                           ng-model="someModel">radio two
                </label>
                <label for="radio3">
                    <input type="radio" value="c" name="someName"
                           id="radio3"
                           aria-checked="false"                             
                           ng-model="someModel">radio three
                </label>
```

when I check the source via firebug of devtools in chrome, I see that 
`aria-invalid` is set to false on all of them. Why? I understand that it is because I have ngModel. But why is `aria-invalid` set to false by default?

Answer (score 0):

If a field is not invalid, `aria-invalid` is set to false. Is the expectation that it only be set after interacting with the form? The only item I could find on this in the [WAI-ARIA spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-invalid) is how it relates to `aria-required`:

> When the user attempts to submit data involving a field for which aria-required is true, authors MAY use the aria-invalid attribute to signal there is an error. However, if the user has not attempted to submit the form, authors SHOULD NOT set the aria-invalid attribute on required widgets simply because the user has not yet entered data.

I suspect the watch function controlling this is falsy at first and therefore outputting a default value of false, changed to true when that condition is truthy. We can change this, the code just has to be updated. **Pull requests are definitely welcome.**

Note: you can opt out of this behavior with the ngAria config if you don't want `aria-invalid` handled at all by configuring `ariaInvalid: false`.

Comment: Is there a way I can disable ariaInvalid in the Angular Material library? If so, how do it do it? Thanks.

Comment: NVM, I know how to do that now.